# Azure B2C authentication and admin login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

we currently work on site that uses Azure B2C authentication for "normal" public users. The site has an admin backend that need "admin" users login. How do you do that? In azure B2C we can't have groups to identify which is an Admin. Can I use custom attributes like Admin-Boolean and set it to true in the Azure users portal? It is secure enough?

Comment: Are administrator users external or internal users? (By external, I mean they sign in and sign up through the Azure AD B2C policies.)

Comment: Yes some admin is external user. Some are intern. But to be simple, I can use only administrators from the B2C external source... I try to add some attributes, but I can't change these attributes from the Azure Portal manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution here IMO.

Yes, you can use custom attributes to solve this problem.

You can set those custom attribute(s) via the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Then in your app you have to check those custom attribute(s).

The first problem with that solution is there has to be an account created to set those claims on.  Depending upon your app this could be an inconvenience or pain point.

You can also set those attribute(s) on sign-up but that requires custom policies which is a whole nother animal IMO

Comment: In this case, An big Private/public site with a admin portail will need 2 authentication approch? Like AD internet for admin and B2C for customer.

Comment: Interesting idea !  That might work nicely.  Depends a little on how you secure your endpoints so it doesn’t become unwieldy.  @Pierre-DSavard